# High-performance message passing from C to Erlang

Tags: c++, c, erlang

I have a C server (a data feed handler) that has the potential to send millions of tiny messages per second across a few thousand long-lived Erlang processes. In a single day, some of these processes will receive a few *thousand* messages, while others will receive tens of *millions*. My interests are threefold:

1. to minimize latency — shortening the length of time from when the C server sends a message to when the Erlang process receives it. A lot of work can be done on things that happen *before* the message is sent or *after* the message is received, but this question is about the link between C and Erlang.
2. to maximize throughput — the faster the better; if the C server can send out 10% more messages per second across all of the Erlang processes, that's a big win.
3. to maximize predictability — if latency or throughput can suddenly degrade by several orders of magnitude due to something like network congestion, that's a big fail.

How can I send messages from a C program to an Erlang process in a high-performance way? What tricks can I do to minimize latency, maximize throughput, or make the communication between Erland and C more predictable? There are many aspects to this. We can choose the protocol for communication between an Erlang program and other programs. We can use Distributed Erlang with a "C Node" for communication between Erlang and C. We can use ports or linked-in drivers.

Comment: Are the Erlang processes and C server running on the same machine?

Comment: `@caf:` The C server is not necessarily on the same machine as any of the Erlang nodes, and it certainly isn't distributed like them. It's the middle man between an external data provider and the Erlang system, like this: `(external-data-source) -> (C-server) -> (Erlang-system)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you invert your system, embed your C code to Erlang VM as linked-in driver. IMHO it is way how you can achieve fastest solution in manageable way.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use [RabbitMQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RabbitMQ)?

You may need a lighter weight solution, but since there is a messaging middleware component already written in Erlang and implementing [AMQP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMQP), it should be easy to try out [RabbitMQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RabbitMQ) and see how it goes...

Comment: RabbitMQ is not your guy if you want minimize latencies and maximal performance. RabbitMQ is general purpose message system with rich routing, configuration and persistence supporting Queue. You can beat it in order of magnitude by specialized tuned solution but you have to invest order of magnitude more time to implementation and tunning.

Comment: It's often used in the non-persistent mode and I did say "you may need a lighter weight solution"...